# Why do I need a 'return' and a new variable?

Tags: python

I am a newbie in Python programming and I would like to understand better the logic of programming. The code below is intended to create a function that assigns its parameters to a dictionary, prompt the user about an artist and a title name, call the function back passing the arguments (given by the user) to the parameters and print the function (the dictionary).

```
def make_album(artist, album_name):
    entry = {'name' : artist, 'album' : album_name}
    return entry

while True:
    print("\nPlease, write your fav artist and title: ")
    print("\nType 'q' to quit.")
    band_name = input('Artist name: ')
    if band_name == 'q':
        break
    title_name = input('Title name: ')
    if title_name == 'q':
        break

comp_entry = make_album(band_name, title_name)
print(comp_entry)
```

The code runs perfectly. But there are two points that I can not understand:

1. Why do I need the 'return entry' line? The function creates a dictionary and it is done. Why a return?
2. Why do I need to create a variable in the end, assign the result of the function and print it? There is already a variable (entry) addressed as the dictionary! I would like to just write instead:

   ```
   make_album(band_name, title_name):
       print(entry)
   ```

I know, the code will not run, but I would be very happy with some words explaining me the reason of why these 2 points.

Comment: The variable ```entry``` has it's scope defined within the method ```make_album()```, i.e. it can only be accessed within the method. We use ```return``` to return this result dictionary. We need to create another variable (```comp_entry```) to store the result of this method, so that we can use it elsewhere.

Comment: Your indentation is off so it might not be an issue, but it seems to me you can type as many artists and albums as you want – and then it stores only one, the last entry. (But do note that if you fix that, you can still only store *one* dict item in a dictionary. You'd probably want a list as well.)

Comment: The variable `entry` lives only inside the function, so it will be lost unless you "return" its value by using `return entry` at the end of the function. What is returned is a value that can be assigned to a new variable, printed, etc. By the way your code does not do what one would expect.

Comment: @usr2564301 thanks and yes, it is to store the last entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`entry` is defined inside the function, so it cannot be accessed outside of it.

Check this article about closures 
http://www.trytoprogram.com/python-programming/python-closures/

Answer (score 1):

What you have to understand is the concept of scope in python. [This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/namespaces-and-scope-in-python/) article is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly print the value this way too

```
print(make_album(band_name, title_name))
```

The variable `comp_entry` is used to store the value **returned** from the `make_album` function. So, if you want a function to return back a value on calling the function, provide a return statement

It will print `None` if no return is provided.